# Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object for int[]

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm facing a problem with Sonar, using Java language, with code below. Sonar states for "Malicious code vulnerability - May expose internal representation by returning reference to mutable object".

```
private int[] integerArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};

public int[] getIntegerArray()
{
    return integerArray;
}
```

all kinds of arryas with 'primitive'+'[]' are mutable?

How to solve this problem, still returning an array of int?

What if, instead of int[], it would be String[], StringBuilder, or AnyObject[]? What would be the solution?

Comment: return `Arrays.copyOf(integerArray, integerArray.length)`.

Comment: All kinds of arrays are mutable, except for zero-length ones.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that callers of the `getIntegerArray()` method can change its contents:

```
int[] arr = yourObject.getIntegerArray();
arr[0] = 12345;

System.out.println(yourObject.getIntegerArray()[0]); // prints 12345.
```

It is generally true of all arrays that they are mutable - whether with primitive or reference elements - except in the specific case of the array having zero length.

The solution  - if you need to return an array - is to make a copy of the array before returning it:

```
return Arrays.copyOf(integerArray, integerArray.length);
```

This solution works for any array.

Comment: Or, in most cases, replace with `List`.